# suggest some online compiler for c/c++

Tags: c++

I am developing a website for which I need an online C/C++ compiler for testing code online.

Is there any possible and feasible solution for this?

I need this compiler so that students can test their code online.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/)

For others languages too!

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this: [Comeau online compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/)

Answer (score 5):

- [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) - C, C++, D, Haskell, Lua, OCaml, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Scheme, Tcl
- [The Zamplizer](http://www.zamples.com/JspExplorer/index.jsp?format=jdk15) Bash, C#, C++, Groovy, Haskell, Java, Perl, Python, Ruby
- [CodeIDE](http://www.codeide.com/) Pascal, BASIC, C++,  Asm, Perl, Javascript, HTML, Flex, MySQL, Prolog,Lisp
- [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) - C/C++

Answer (score 3):

There's one: [Online Compiler](http://www.onlinecompiler.net/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a normal compiler and redirect the stdout and stderr to your website. Afaik there is no existing solution for this but you could ask the guys from [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) how they made it.

Comment: From php this wouldn't be hard. Just get the output, run <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php">fwrite()</a> to write the file, then use <a href="http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php">exec()</a> to run gcc on it, then another exec() on the compiled program. It's not particularly secure at all though..

Answer (score 1):

I only know the [Comeau online compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/).

For sure this is the compiler people refer to when then want to know whether a code snippet respects the ISO C++ Standard (including upcoming new C++0x features)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ideone.com](http://ideone.com)

Answer (score 1):

[liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/) 
gcc-4.6.0 release + boost-1.46.1