# Is there a fiddle type thing for c++ and other languages?

Tags: c++, c

I remember seeing once a jsfiddle type of thing (online compiler) where you can specify the language (c, c++, asm) and the input and output and it compiles it and displays the output from the website.

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [suggest some online compiler for c/c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778209/suggest-some-online-compiler-for-c-c)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are many, two most popularly used here in SO are:

[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/)
[codepad.org](http://codepad.org/)

And all you have to do to find more is use google. A simple search yields thousands of [results](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&rls=com.microsoft:*&q=online%20c%2b%2b%20compiler&oq=online%20c%2b%2b%20compiler&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=55091018l55095471l0l19l16l0l7l7l0l438l2063l2-2.2.2&safe=active). I usually stick the two I mentioned above because I have seen them working reliably.

Comment: It appears that ideone supports more programming languages than codepad.

Comment: A google search now yields this page at the top result ;)

Comment: Ideone is better, faster and allows post-submit edit of the code... And it has a colored syntax-highlighting and many other good feaetures :) , also Coding ground on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

[codepad](http://codepad.org) and [ideone](http://ideone.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [codepad](http://codepad.org/), but it doesn't have input options afaik.

[ideone](https://ideone.com/) is created for programming contests, like [spoj](http://www.spoj.pl/), and allows input, output and file saving.

Answer (score 1):

You can now find most of the fiddles at https://fiddles.io/